# inject library dependencies into django model

Tags: python, django-models, dependency-injection

I have a Django model that makes use of some libraries which I would like to be able to override. For instance, when testing I'd like to pass a mock instead of having my model tightly coupled. I can do this in python, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it with a Django model. Here's a simplified example not using Django:

```
import requests

class APIClient:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.http_lib = kwargs.get("http_lib", requests)

  def get_url(self, url):
    return self.http_lib.get(url)
```

For regular use of this class I can still use `requests` but if I want to use a different library for some reason or if I want to test certain outcomes, I can invoke the class with `client = APIClient(http_lib=MockRequests())`

But how do I do that with a Django model? If I try to pass kwargs that aren't backed by a database field Django throws an error. Overriding `__init__` is not considered a good practice either. Is there a way in Django to set and get a value that isn't backed by a database column?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `settings.TEST` var? If so, you could make `http_lib` a function that returns the proper lib:

```
from django.conf import settings

def get_http_lib(mock=None):
    if not mock:
        return requests
    return MockRequests()

class APIClient(Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # ...whatever...

    @property
    def some_column(self):
        http_lib = get_http_lib(settings.TEST)
        # ...etc...
```

Not ideal, but passable.

---

PRE-EDIT ANSWER (doesn't work):

What if you [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) subsequent to instantiating the `Model`?

```
# In model...
class APIClient(Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.http_lib = requests
    # ...etc...

# In tests...
client = APIClient()
setattr(client, 'http_lib', MockRequests())
```

Comment: That would work for a non-Django object, but the problem is that Django seems to expect every property to be associated with a database column. So I can't find a way to runtime dependency injection on a Django model like I do with other python classes.

Comment: You make me struggle, but i'm almost sure i've used `__init__` with django models and it worked as well as regular python object `__init__`. It's triggered even on Model.objects.create, so i guess you can runtime DI inside of `__init__`.